# How to Resize a image file using photoshop script

Tags: adobe, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to resize an image file into two images with different sizes: 240pxX240px, 1024pxX1024px,
Also I want to maintain aspect ratio.
How to do this using photoshop script?

Thanks

Comment: `image processor` option is available but it generates only 1 image, i want to output two images per click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple action with Ps using the File->Automate->Fit Image... command to do the resizing.

To create the action...

1. Open the action panel: Window->Actions.
2. Then Create a new action by clicking [image] at the bottom of the action panel.
3. Name your action, when you see that the record button is red, [image] you're recording, so don't do anything that you don't want to be done every time you run the action.
4. Choose File->Automate->Fit Image... put 1024 in the height and 1024 in the width and click <kbd>OK</kbd>
5. Choose File->Save As and choose an empty folder to save them to, do not change the name of the file, this is so that you will be able to run this action on an entire folder of images without overwriting them each time the action is run.
6. Repeat step 4 but use 240 for both the height and width.
7. Save As to a *new folder* (again, don't change the name of the file)
8. Close the file without saving.
9. Hit stop [image] at the bottom of the Actions Panel
10. Now, using Bridge, browse to the folder containing your images and select the ones that you want to resize this way.
11. Choose Tools->Photoshop->Batch.
12. Pick the action that you just created from the Action drop down and then click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Photoshop will now open each file, resize the image to 1024x1024, save it, resize it to 240x240, save it, close the original and then repeat for the next image that is selected in Bridge. It will continue until it has processed all of the images you've selected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am looking for script to resize image.

Comment: I followed your steps but the 1024x1024 & 240x240 resolution files are getting overrided.

Comment: files are getting replaced. (From 2 source files I am getting only 2 files instead of 4)

Comment: You'll want to make sure to save the small files to a different folder than the large ones (see step 7).